# Is there a difference between Count() (linq extension) and List<T>.Count

Tags: c#, list

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"};
IEnumerable<string> enumerable = list;

int c1 = list.Count;
int c2 = list.Count();
int c3 = enumerable.Count();
```

Are there differences in performance and implementation between these last 3 statements? Will `list.Count()` perform worse or the same as `list.Count`, and does it matter if the reference is of type `IEnumerable<string>` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look with Reflector:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    ICollection<TSource> is2 = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (is2 != null)
    {
        return is2.Count;
    }
    ICollection is3 = source as ICollection;
    if (is3 != null)
    {
        return is3.Count;
    }
    int num = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

So, if your [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) implements [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) or [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx), it will return the `Count` property.

Answer (score 3):

The Linq Count method is clever enough not to iterate over the underlying collection if it implements ICollection interface and therefore already has Count property.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the count on `IEnumerable` first checks if the enumerable list also implements `ICollection<T>` where T is the generic parameter of the enumerable list.

If it does, it returns `ICollection<T>.Count`.

If not, it checks if it implements `ICollection`. If it does it returns `ICollection.Count`.

If it does not implement neither of those it has to iterate through the entire list and count, and this might be a expensive operation for a big list.

`List<string>` however implements `ICollection<string>` and therefore the performance will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it works like this: a List keeps its own count in a variable. Count() loops through the IEnumerable to count the number of elements. That would make List.Count more efficient.

Comment: If the IEnumerable is an ICollection (such as a List) therefore having the .Count property then Linq does use this as a shortcut when you use the .Count() method. This means that whichever you use doesn't really matter.

Comment: This is wrong. Count() is coded to that it only loops through to count if the element you are calling Count() on does not implement ICollection itself.